# Linux output redirection to file

Tags: shell, awk, io-redirection

This is in RHEL 7.

Simple shell script:

```
while [ 1 ] ;
do
  echo "Test Message 1"
  echo "Test Message 2"
  echo ""
  sleep 10
done
```

Following works fine:

```
./loop-test.sh | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }'
[2023-12-21 10:04:47] Test Message 1
[2023-12-21 10:04:47] Test Message 2
```

I want to redirect output to a file. So, I did:
./loop-test.sh | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' > t.txt

It creates output file t.txt, but it is empty. I tried several redirections... including "tee" with no luck.

Is there a way I can capture the output in a file?

Comment: This is also [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009)

Comment: How long did you wait for checking t.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to output buffering. When the output is redirected to a file, both `gawk` and the `shell` buffer the output before writing it to the file. To disable buffering in `gawk`, you can use the ***[`fflush()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-fflush_0028_0029-function)*** function. Something like:

```bash
./loop-test.sh | gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0; fflush() }' > t.txt
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/SqueakyPettySpreadsheet#main.sh)***

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that have "been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks. My bad sorry. I missed to check for its probable duplication.